# Storing Data In a Relational Database Query

Tags: php, mysqli

When creating a many to many table, relational database. If for example you are enabling users to scrape images form around the web and tag them. 
Would it be better to:

1. Check to see if the image is already in the database and if it is, create a link in a relational table and if it is not create a new image.
2. Create a unique instance of the image for every user and when looking to display the most popular images SELECT AND ORDER BY the image with the most duplicates

I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have something equivalent to a `USERS` table and a `PICTURES` table.  Also a table to break up the many to many relationship.  `U2P` I will call it.

The option you listed as option 1 would seem to be the preferred way.  Check to see if the picture is in the DB, if it is get primary key from `PICTURES` corresponding to it.  If not, put the picture in the `PICTURES` table.

Regardless of if it is a new image, or one that is already in there, you will insert the event into the `U2P` table.  This would reference the `USERS` primary key and the `PICTURES` primary key corresponding to the event.  You would also record other data such as time etc...

Comment: Thanks NR, i was just thinking about when displaying popular images, if each user can give the image a title, when displaying the image in a 'most popular' list which title do you use. I was just looking to gather opinions really, finding out some "unknown unknowns" if you will. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: you have some choices then, the easiest will be to put the `title` column in the event table.  To get the most popular it is as simple as a `select count(*)` from the event tables where the picture pk matches.  To get them all at the same time you can use a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` to get them all in a single query, sorted however you like.  There are still options for saving the title.  If multiple users call it different things for example, which will you use?  This may require more thought.  Easiest may be to use the first title given.